Stored procedure to get the lowest price of each product and show columns that are not in GROUP BY clause
I'm building a stored procedure that returns the lowest price of each product and show their respective store info and date. This SP should allow optional parameters for StoreCity and ProdType. I'm a bit stuck on the SELECT query.
These are the tables:
+-----------+
| Product   |
+-----------+
| id_prod   |
| prod_type |
+-----------+

+-----------+
| Store     |
+-----------+
| idStore   |
| StoreName |
| StoreCity |
+-----------+

+---------------+
| Product_Store |
+---------------+
| fkStore       |
| fkProd        |
| PriceProd     |
| PriceDate     |
+---------------+

At first, I was trying this:
SELECT fkProd, MIN(PriceProd)
FROM Product_Store
GROUP BY fkProd;

to get this:
+---------+---------------+
| fkProd  | MIN(PriceProd)|
+---------+---------------+
|       1 |          1.11 |
|       2 |          0.11 |
|       3 |          1.11 |
|       4 |          0.11 |
+---------+---------------+

It's close to what I expected, but I also need the fkStore and PriceDate. So I use the query below, but (as far as I can see) it won't allow me to use parameters (they should be in the first SELECT within the WITH clause, right?)
WITH q AS (
    SELECT 
        fkStore, 
        fkProd, 
        PriceProd, row_number() over (partition by fkProd order by PriceProd ASC) MinPrice,
        PriceDate
    FROM Product_Store)
SELECT 
    Store.StoreName, 
    Product.ProdType, 
    PriceProd, 
    PriceDate
FROM q
INNER JOIN Store ON q.fkStore = Store.idStore
INNER JOIN Product ON q.fkProd = Product.idProd
WHERE MinPrice = 1


If you are looking for a stored procedure-based answer below would do.

This is achieved using a common table transaction also known as
(CTE)

Refer the below SQL code:
CREATE PROCEDURE LowestProductPrices
    @StoreCity NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @ProdType NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    WITH MinPriceCommonTableExpression AS (
        SELECT 
            fkProd, 
            fkStore, 
            MIN(PriceProd) AS MinPrice,
            MIN(PriceDate) AS MinPriceDate 
        FROM 
            Product_Store
        GROUP BY 
            fkProd, fkStore
    ),
    ProductWithMinPrice AS (
        SELECT 
            ps.fkProd, 
            ps.fkStore, 
            ps.PriceProd, 
            ps.PriceDate
        FROM 
            Product_Store ps
        INNER JOIN 
            MinPriceCommonTableExpression mp ON ps.fkProd = mp.fkProd AND ps.PriceProd = mp.MinPrice
    )
    SELECT 
        p.id_prod AS ProductID,
        p.prod_type AS ProductType,
        s.StoreName,
        s.StoreCity,
        pm.PriceProd,
        pm.PriceDate
    FROM 
        ProductWithMinPrice pm
    INNER JOIN 
        Store s ON pm.fkStore = s.idStore
    INNER JOIN 
        Product p ON pm.fkProd = p.id_prod
    WHERE 
        (@StoreCity IS NULL OR s.StoreCity = @StoreCity) AND
        (@ProdType IS NULL OR p.prod_type = @ProdType)
    ORDER BY 
        p.id_prod;
END

Update:
MySQL version of the above stored procedure is as follows:
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE LowestProductPrices(
    IN StoreCity VARCHAR(100),
    IN ProdType VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    -- Temporary table to store minimum prices
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MinPriceTemp AS
    SELECT 
        fkProd, 
        fkStore, 
        MIN(PriceProd) AS MinPrice,
        MIN(PriceDate) AS MinPriceDate 
    FROM 
        Product_Store
    GROUP BY 
        fkProd, fkStore;

    -- Temporary table to store products with minimum prices
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ProductWithMinPrice AS
    SELECT 
        ps.fkProd, 
        ps.fkStore, 
        ps.PriceProd, 
        ps.PriceDate
    FROM 
        Product_Store ps
    INNER JOIN 
        MinPriceTemp mp ON ps.fkProd = mp.fkProd AND ps.PriceProd = mp.MinPrice;

    -- Select final results set API
    SELECT 
        p.id_prod AS ProductID,
        p.prod_type AS ProductType,
        s.StoreName,
        s.StoreCity,
        pm.PriceProd,
        pm.PriceDate
    FROM 
        ProductWithMinPrice pm
    INNER JOIN 
        Store s ON pm.fkStore = s.idStore
    INNER JOIN 
        Product p ON pm.fkProd = p.id_prod
    WHERE 
        (StoreCity IS NULL OR s.StoreCity = StoreCity) AND
        (ProdType IS NULL OR p.prod_type = ProdType)
    ORDER BY 
        p.id_prod;

    -- Drop temporary created tables
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS MinPriceTemp;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ProductWithMinPrice;
END //

DELIMITER ;

Note that in MySQL we use IN clause for input parameters and CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to hold the intermediary result set of data. Once the final result set is collected temporary tables are being dropped.

This uses Microsoft SQL Server syntax, but the question was tagged for MySQL. Each vendor's stored procedure language is different. A solution for one brand won't be recognized by other brands.

This should work:
SELECT Product_Store.fkPROD,MIN(PriceProd),PriceDate,StoreName AS "MinPrice" 
FROM Product JOIN Product_Store ON id_prod=fkPROD 
JOIN Store ON idStore=fkStore 
GROUP BY Product_Store.fkPROD;


In order to get your desired result with optional parameters you can create an SP like:
DELIMITER 

CREATE PROCEDURE GetLowestPricePerProduct(
    IN StoreCity VARCHAR(100),
    IN ProdType VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        p.id_prod,
        p.prod_type,
        s.StoreName,
        s.StoreCity,
        ps.PriceProd,
        ps.PriceDate
    FROM 
        Product p
        INNER JOIN Product_Store ps ON p.id_prod = ps.fkProd
        INNER JOIN Store s ON ps.fkStore = s.idStore
    WHERE 
        (s.StoreCity = StoreCity OR StoreCity IS NULL)
        AND (p.prod_type = ProdType OR ProdType IS NULL)
        AND ps.PriceProd = (
            SELECT MIN(ps2.PriceProd)
            FROM Product_Store ps2
            WHERE ps2.fkProd = p.id_prod
        )
    ORDER BY 
        p.id_prod, ps.PriceDate;
END 

DELIMITER ;

Call SP like:
CALL GetLowestPricePerProduct(NULL, NULL);

Or
CALL GetLowestPricePerProduct('New York', 'Electronics');

and get underlying results:



id_prod
prod_type
StoreName
StoreCity
PriceProd
PriceDate




1
Electronics
BestBuy
New York
279.99
2024-02-01


2
Groceries
Target
Chicago
13.99
2024-01-01


3
Clothing
Target
Chicago
44.99
2024-01-01



Hope this is what you needed
